# Checklist for colour detection in a specified order

Tags: python

This is a rough idea for the code I have issue with. Firstly 5 random numbers (1-5) generated and stored into a list, next the colour detection starts and each colour detected by the camera will be checked to see if it matches with the first index of the RNG list. If it matches, the colour detected will be appended to a list and repeats till 5 colours are in the colour list. (5 different colours)

```py
import random

check = [0,0,0,0,0]

randomlist = []
for i in range(0,5):
    n = random.randint(1,5)
    randomlist.append(n)



while check[4] != 1:   
    testlist = []
    for i in range(0,5):
        n = random.randint(1,5)
        testlist.append(n)

    if testlist[0] != randomlist[0]:
        check[0] = 0
    else:
        check[0] = 1
    
        if testlist[1] != randomlist[1]:
            check[1] = 0
        else:
            check[1] = 1
        
            if testlist[2] != randomlist[2]:
                check[2] = 0
            else:
                check[2] = 1

                if testlist[3] != randomlist[3]:
                    check[3] = 0
                else:
                    check[3] = 1
                
                    if testlist[4] != randomlist[4]:
                        check[4] = 0
                    else:
                        check[4] = 1
```

Comment: Please edit your question with a clear statement of the problem and do not shout. Large bold font is not appropriate here.

Comment: I've fixed the awful formatting and removed the opencv tag since this doesn't use opencv. -- you really should take the [tour], review [ask] and [mre].